# (Python) Sorting in decreasing sequence of the last element in a namedtuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, tuples, namedtuple

I am trying to sort a list of named tuples by their last 'element', in decreasing sequence (from largest to smallest). Here's a snippet of the list of namedtuples that I am trying to sort:

```
>>> a =[]
>>> a += [p]
>>> a
[Point(x=11, y=22)]
>>> total = []
>>> b = Point(1,33)
>>> b
Point(x=1, y=33)
>>> c = Point(99, 2)
>>> total += [b] + [c] + [p]
>>> total
[Point(x=1, y=33), Point(x=99, y=2), Point(x=11, y=22)]
>>> sorted(total, key = lambda x: x[y], reverse = True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
    sorted(total, key = lambda x: x[y], reverse = True)
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <lambda>
    sorted(total, key = lambda x: x[y], reverse = True)
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
>>> sorted(total, key = lambda x: x['y'], reverse = True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#27>", line 1, in <module>
    sorted(total, key = lambda x: x['y'], reverse = True)
  File "<pyshell#27>", line 1, in <lambda>
    sorted(total, key = lambda x: x['y'], reverse = True)
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

However, I keep getting the errors above.. Is there a way to do this for such instances of namedtuple?

As a rough guide, the list of namedtuples is `total`, and I am trying to sort the tuples from largest `y` to smallest `y`. So the result should look something like:

```
>>> total
[Point(x=1, y=33), Point(x=11, y=22), Point(x=99, y=2)]
```

The documentation for namedtuple can be found at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple.

Thanks and some help will be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the following:

```
sorted(total, key = lambda x: x.y, reverse = True)
```

Comment: Thank you! Silly mistake on my part

Comment: Yes! I am waiting for the the 15 minute mark as stackoverflow does not allow me to accept the answer within 15 minutes of posting the question haha. You answered too quickly ;)